# How do I configure Dual Domain SAS for my D2600 enclosure and Linux

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, sas

I'm investigating how one would go about setting up dual domain SAS with a D2600 and two identical HP cards for the following: P411, P421, P431, P441, P822 or the P841

I've tried searching but I can't seem to find any documentation that explains this.

Is it done through the hpacucli utility?

Answer (score 1):

Dual-domain isn't supported in that configuration, see [this](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04111697.pdf) link.

Comment: thanks what if I have an p812 card -- how do I go about configuring it? -- I'll update my question ... thanks.

Comment: Let me read that for you, in paragraph two - "On HPE ProLiant and Integrity servers Dual Domain support is available for the HPE
Smart Array P411, P421, P431, P441, P822 or the P841 Controllers attached to a D2600/D2700." So no.

Comment: my bad ... I was reading another doc -- let me read your link in detail and update he question